# Operator on infinite dimensional Hilbert space: domain and range

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, linear-algebra

Since a QM operator is a linear map, it is useful to think about them as functions.  An operator $\hat A$ on a finite $N$-dimensional Hilbert space $H_N$ is always such that
$$\hat A:H_N\to H_N.$$

The domain and range of $\hat A$ are both $H_N$.  $\hat A$ operates on states in Hilbert space and returns states in Hilbert space.  My question regards the range of an operator $\hat B$ on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space $H_\infty$.  If an operator always returns an eigenstate, we must write
$$\hat B:H_\infty\not\to H_\infty,$$

because the eigenstate of an operator with a continuous spectrum cannot live in Hilbert space.  The range cannot be the domain.  So, what is the function notation $\hat B:H_\infty\to X$ appropriate for operators with continuous spectra?

Regarding the physics, I want to know about the mechanism by which the position operator can operate on a state to kick it out of the Hilbert space by returning a Dirac $\delta$ position eigenstate.  I am aware that the rigged Hilbert space formalism offers a space for the position eigenstate to live in, but I am curious as to how this is described in the usual theory of linear operators on Hilbert space.

Comment: Note first that in an infinite dimensional Hilbert space the domain of an operator is usually not the whole space, but in QM one is interested in operators whose domain is _dense_ in the Hilbert space. Then, the operators on the Hilbert space does not kick states out of the Hilbert space.

Comment: So then the operator must not return one of its eigenvalues, at which point I arrive at that which I am missing.  Does the operator not have to return an eigenvalue?  Please explain.

Comment: I don't understand the question - the position operator *never* produces an "eigenstate" when acting on vectors inside the Hilbert space, precisely because its spectrum is purely continuous. The part of the question that starts at *"If an operator always returns an eigenstate"* makes no sense - why should an operator "always return an eigenstate"? What does that even mean?

Comment: Is it one of the axioms of QM that observables are represented by linear operators?  And it is not a result in linear algebra that all linear operators return an eigenvalue?  And is not true that each (non-degenerate) eigenvalue has one corresponding eigenvector?  And if all of these things are true, is it not required that a linear operator with a continuous spectrum acting on a state in its domain of self-adjointness must collapse the state to an eigenstate, otherwise the operator would not be able to return an eigenvector?

Comment: @hodopsmith "Is it not a result in linear algebra that all linear operators return an eigenvalue?" No, certainly not, though its a bit hard to say what that even means. More to the point, operators with purely continuous spectra do not even *have* eigenvalues or eigenvectors in a strict sense.

Comment: @J.Murray The Dirac delta function $\delta(x-x_0)$ is the eigenstate of the position operator having eigenvalue $x_0$. I asked this rhetorically: "Is it not a result in linear algebra that all linear operators return an eigenvalue?"  When we're talking about self-adjoint operators in QM, they do all return an eigenvalue.  This is taught in the first week of every QM class on earth.  I think what J Murray may mean while failing to communicate his thinking is that operators with continuous spectra don't have eigenvectors in Hilbert space.  That's completely different than not having them.

Comment: @hodopsmith The Dirac delta is not an element of $L^2(\mathbb R)$, so it obviously can't be an eigenvector of an operator which is defined on a *subset* of $L^2(\mathbb R)$. It can be understood as a *generalized* eigenvector by invoking the rigged Hilbert space formalism, but you explicitly said you don't want to talk about that. And again, self-adjoint operators do not "return an eigenvalue." That terminology doesn't even make sense. Are you saying that the *measurement* of an observable represented by self-adjoint operator must return an eigenvalue? Because that's **very** different [...]

Comment: [...] from talking about the action of the operator on vectors in the Hilbert space. It's also strictly **not true** for operators with continuous spectra, precisely because they have no eigenvectors or eigenvalues. The machinery for dealing with purely continuous spectra is far more complex than what is necessary when dealing with operators with discrete spectra, which is why you don't learn about it in the first week of a typical QM class.

Comment: @J.Murray If you think $\hat x|x\rangle=x|x\rangle$ doesn't make sense, or you think it is an abuse of terminology to describe this as "$\hat x$ returning eigenvalue $x$," then I do not think you are familiar with QM at the level needed to answer my question.  Thank you for your participation, however!  Great effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The appropriate generalisation of eigenvalues of an operator $A$ on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ is the spectrum $\sigma(A)$ consisting of those $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ for which $\lambda - A$ does not admit a bounded inverse. The spectrum of a self-adjoint operator A with domain of self-adjointness $D(A)$ dense in $\mathcal{H}$ can be split into two parts: The **discrete spectrum** and the **essential** (or continuous) **spectrum**. The discrete spectrum consists of all isolated eigenvalues in $\sigma(A)$ with finite multiplicity, the essential spectrum of all other spectral values. If $\lambda$ lies in the spectrum, then, by [Weyl's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_spectrum), a sequence $(\psi_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ of normalised elements in $D(A)$ exists such that $\| A\psi_k - \lambda \psi_k\| \to 0$ as $k\to \infty$ (i.e. $A\psi_k$ approximates $\lambda \psi_k$). If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, simply take the constant sequence that consists of an eigenvector. If $\lambda$ lies in the essential spectrum, then $(\psi_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ can be chosen to have no convergent subsequence. Sometimes such a sequence is then called an approximate eigenvector.

**Example**: Let $X: D(X) \subset L^2(\mathbb{R}) \to L^2(\mathbb{R})$ be the position operator defined by $X\psi(x) = x\psi(x)$ for $\psi \in D(X)$, where $D(X)$ is the domain of $X$ that makes $X$ self-adjoint. It is known that $\sigma(X) = \mathbb{R}$. Let $x_0 \in \sigma(X)$. Naively, $\delta_{x_0}$ is an eigenfunction of $X$ with eigenvalue $x_0$ because
$$X\delta_{x_0}(x) = x \delta_{x_0}(x) = x_0 \delta_{x_0}(x).$$
However, $\delta_{x_0} \notin D(X)$ (and not even in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$). But $\delta_{x_0}$ can be approximated by normalised functions $f_\epsilon \in D(X)$, e.g.
$$|f_\epsilon(x)|^2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\epsilon}} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{2\epsilon}}.$$
Indeed, Weyl's criterion is satisfied because
$$\| Xf_\epsilon - x_0f_\epsilon\|^2_{L^2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\epsilon}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} (x-x_0)^2 \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{2\epsilon}} \mathrm{d}x \stackrel{\epsilon \to 0}{\longrightarrow} 0. $$

Comment: Thanks!  Are you saying that the position operator takes a state in Hilbert space and simply returns a state in the spectrum of the position operator $\hat x:H_\infty\to\sigma(\hat x)$?  Also, is your reference to Weyl's criterion meant to state that any position eigenstate can be approximated to arbitrary precision by wavepackets that do exist in the Hilbert space, and that we can then substitute those "approximate eigenvectors" into the spectrum of $\hat x$ to avoid $\hat x$ kicking states out of Hilbert space?

Comment: The spectrum of an operator is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$, so it does not contain any states.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I meant it returns one of its eigenvectors whose eigenvalue is in the spectrum.  How can we let $X: D(X) \subset L^2(\mathbb{R}) \to L^2(\mathbb{R})$  when the eigenstates of of $X$ are not in $ L^2(\mathbb{R})$, as you yourself say?  That limit at the end of the your example is exactly the thing that is not in $ L^2(\mathbb{R})$.  Do I have to settle for the convention being that we use an approximation and don't require that $X$ returns an eigenvector?